# Hibernate HQL Projection Using Entities ManyToMany Definitions Issue

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa, hql

**Problem:** HQL query is not returning any results when I reference an entities collection field as part of the HQL statement. It works for one HQL projection for example like this:

```sql
select inc.categoryTypes as categoryTypes from IncidentEntity inc where (inc.id = :id105019)
```

The categoryTypes is one of the IncidentEntity classes fields (which is a collection defined as a ManyToMany join as seen below). This works fine, but the issue arises when I am attempting to reference another projection collection that is mapped as a ManyToMany join.

```sql
select inc.categoryTypes as categoryTypes, inc.consequences as consequences from IncidentEntity inc where (inc.id = :id105019)
```

As soon as I do it like this, I get an empty set. Which means the SQL query that hibernate generates isn't returning anything. I have verified this by executing the command within SQL Manager which returns no results.

Here is the IncidentEntity:

```java
/**
 * Database entity for the 'incidents' table records.<br>
 * Entity domain object is {@link nz.co.doltech.ims.shared.domains.Incident}
 * @author Ben Dol
 * 
 */
@javax.persistence.Entity(name = "incidents")
@Cache(usage=CacheConcurrencyStrategy.TRANSACTIONAL)
public class IncidentEntity implements Entity {

    ...

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "incident_categorytype", joinColumns = { 
            @JoinColumn(name = "incident_id") }, 
        inverseJoinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "categorytype_id") 
    })
    private Set<CategoryTypeEntity> categoryTypes = new HashSet<CategoryTypeEntity>();

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "incident_consequence", joinColumns = { 
            @JoinColumn(name = "incident_id") }, 
        inverseJoinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "consequence_id") 
    })
    private Set<ConsequenceEntity> consequences = new HashSet<ConsequenceEntity>();

    ...

    public Set<CategoryTypeEntity> getCategoryTypes() {
        return categoryTypes;
    }
    public void setCategoryTypes(Set<CategoryTypeEntity> categoryTypes) {
        this.categoryTypes = categoryTypes;
    }

    public Set<ConsequenceEntity> getConsequences() {
        return consequences;
    }
    public void setConsequences(Set<ConsequenceEntity> consequences) {
        this.consequences = consequences;
    }

    ...
}
```

CategoryTypeEntity relationship definition:

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "categoryTypes")
private Set<IncidentEntity> incidents = new HashSet<IncidentEntity>();
```

ConsequenceEntity relationship definition:

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "consequences")
private Set<IncidentEntity> incidents = new HashSet<IncidentEntity>();
```

Data structure:

[image: relationship-diagram]

Using **Hibernate 3.6.10**

Maybe I have setup the definitions wrong, or I am missing a limitation with the HQL here, I'm not sure. Would appreciate any help that I could get here. Thanks!

Regards,
Ben

Comment: I am trying to genrate this but in my case i m getting the list if i select both many-to-many relationship.

Comment: This is really strange. Is your many-to-many definition being setup the same as us mine here? Perhaps my relationship definition is missing something important. Updated my post with the other side of the relationship definition if you could check it. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: Yes all is same In my case I have Class1 which has many relationship with Class2 and with Class3. I have done mapping through xml but that doesn't make diff.

Comment: Nope, still no idea why its not working...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You know that you are generating a Cartesian product with this query, right?

The query can be better visualized as:

```
select categoryTypes, consequences 
from IncidentEntity inc 
inner join inc.categoryTypes as categoryTypes
inner join inc.consequences as consequences
where (inc.id = :id105019)
```

Because you haven't specify an explicit join, an INNER JOIN is assumed not a LEFT JOIN.

Let's assume there are categories for the specified incident. So this query will return the categories for this incident, which is what you also reported:

```
select categoryTypes
from IncidentEntity inc 
inner join inc.categoryTypes as categoryTypes
where (inc.id = :id105019)
```

But when there are no consequences, the INNER JOIN will return no result, so:

```
select categoryTypes, consequences 
from IncidentEntity inc 
inner join inc.consequences as consequences
where (inc.id = :id105019)
```

will not return anything, but then this can happen for your query too:

```
select categoryTypes, consequences 
from IncidentEntity inc 
inner join inc.categoryTypes as categoryTypes
inner join inc.consequences as consequences
where (inc.id = :id105019)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, how can I make Hibernate assume a LEFT JOIN in the HQL query?

Comment: You need to substitute inner with left in my example queries and then you will have left joins instead.

Comment: Is there a way to make hibernate assume this? Like in the relationship definition.